# Problems with Grub - Ubuntu error while installing alongside Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, multi-boot, grub2

I tried installing Ubuntu alongside Windows. I did this using a bootable USB with Ubuntu LTS and using the "install alongside Windows" option. Unfortunately there was FATAL error and now when I boot up it boots up to grub NOT windows.

I am still able to boot to windows by entering the command `enter` twice. I then re-deleted what would have been the ubuntu partition, however it still boots to Ubuntu.

Also when I attempt to boot into my USB (by going on Windows 8.1 and holding SHIFT while clicking the restart button and clicking "Choose another device" on the windows blue screen), it instead boots to GRUB.

Therefore I have the following questions:

1. How do I boot to my USB so I can reinstall Ubuntu?
2. How do I boot to Windows instead of Grub?
3. How do I get rid of this Grub thing altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple. I like painless ways to do things. I do it a different way.

Boot to Windows and install a tiny little program called [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). It is free. That's what I use.  And I have both Windows 8.1 and Debian Jessie 8 installed with absolutely zero issues.

You have to configure the program to ADD a linux loader.  After you install it, you'll see what I am talking about. I'm on Debian or I would pull it up.

It is the painless way to dual boot.

These are the steps I took.

1. I used Gparted to split my disk. Half for ext4 and half for NTFS.
2. I installed windows 8.1 FIRST.
3. I installed EasyBCD and configured it to ADD a menu for Linux.  It auto finds Windows.
4. Then I installed Debian with KDE and when it asked where to install GRUB, I used the default which is the mount point --- /

Then reboot your computer.  And you're done.

This works for any linux distro... You don't need to use the usb stick to dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Boot-Repair** to solve your problem.

Follow the steps:

1.Make a live bootable USB installed with any version of Ubuntu OS.

2.Live boot into Ubuntu OS.

3.Then Install Boot-repair.

4.Launch Boot-repair,click "Recommended Repair" option.

Once repair is finished, restart your computer.

Refer:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Thanks.